# Add column containing list value if column contains string in list

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, isin

I'm trying to scan a particular column in a dataframe, eg `df['x']` for values which I have in a separate list `list = ['y', 'z', 'a', 'b']`. How do I make pandas load a new column with the list value if `df['x']` contains any, or more than one of the values from the list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
In [720]: import pandas as pd
In [719]: if df['x'].str.contains('|'.join(list)).any(): 
     ...:     df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(list)], axis=1)) 
     ...:
```